# How to declare queue with MessageListener

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I use Spring Boot 2.2 and need to receive message via JMS.

I saw then we can use annotation

```java
@Component
public class JMSReceiver {

    @JmsListener(destination = "queue")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
    }
}
```

Implement `MessageListener`:

```java
@Component
public class JMSReceiver implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
       ...    
    }
}
```

With the `MessageListener` how we declare queue we use?

Answer (score 3):

You don't declare the queue on the `MessageListener` implementation, but on the `MessageListenerContainer`.

For example:

```
  @Bean
  public MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
      DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
      container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
      container.setDestinationName("queue"); // Set the queue name here.
      container.setMessageListener(jmsReceiver()); // Your JMS receiver message listener.
      return container;
  }
```

Comment: if you need to read many queue, seem easier to use @JmsListener

Comment: That's correct: `@JmsListener` makes things easy, and creates the listener container above behind the scenes.  Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-annotated

Comment: I also had to add this line to pass the actual queue:
container.setDestination(jMSManager.getCoreInQueue());

Answer (score 2):

The message Listener interface has only one method "onMessage".

```
public interface MessageListener {
    void onMessage(Message message);
}
```

As soon as messages arrives at the destination, the message consumer delivers them by calling the message listener’s onMessage() method. Registering a message listener allows clients to asynchronously receive messages without having to block/poll the message consumer. So We have to register the "Message Listener" in the "Message Consumer" because Messages are received by a message consumer,So the queues are set in "Message Consumer" (The below example demonstrates it)Here below is the "Message Consumer" Interface:

```
public interface MessageConsumer {
    String getMessageSelector() throws JMSException;
    MessageListener getMessageListener() throws JMSException;
    void setMessageListener(MessageListener listener) throws JMSException;
    Message receive() throws JMSException;
    Message receive(long timeout) throws JMSException;
    Message receiveNoWait() throws JMSException;
    void close() throws JMSException;
}
```

So Here below is the code which can help you ,

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class ConsumerMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    private String consumerName;

    public ConsumerMessageListener(String consumerName) {
        this.consumerName = consumerName;
    }

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        try {
            System.out.println(consumerName + " received "
                    + textMessage.getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Queue Creation is done here and Messages are send from here.

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;


import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;

public class JmsMessageListenerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, Exception {
        BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI(
                "broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)"));
        broker.start();
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            // Producer
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                    "tcp://localhost:61616");
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue("customerQueue");
            String payload = "Important Task";
            Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            System.out.println("Sending text '" + payload + "'");
            producer.send(msg);

            // Consumer
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            consumer.setMessageListener(new ConsumerMessageListener("Consumer"));
            connection.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            session.close();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
            broker.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Sending Messages from Controller and receiving Using Spring Boot :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/transaction")
public class BackOfficeController {
  @Autowired private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
  @PostMapping("/send")
  public void send(@RequestBody BackOfficeVO transaction) {
    System.out.println("Sending a transaction.");
    // Post message to the message queue named "BackOfficeTransactionQueue"
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("BackOfficeTransactionQueue", transaction);
  }
}

@Component
public class BackOfficeReceiver {
  @Autowired
  private BackOfficeTransactionRepository transactionRepository;
  @JmsListener(destination = "BackOfficeTransactionQueue", containerFactory = "myFactory")
  public void receiveMessage(BackOfficeVO transaction) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + transaction + ">");
    transactionRepository.save(transaction);
  }
}
```

To add Up If you are using an Existing Message Listener You can Just define It in the bean:

```
<bean id="messageListener" class="ConsumerMessageListener"/>


<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>
</bean>
```

Source :
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jms/jms-messagelistener-example/
https://dzone.com/articles/using-jms-in-spring-boot-1
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-receiving-async